# Modifying a WordPress Plugin

Tags: functions, customization, actions

is it possible to modify plugin by removing action and then adding a new with new function?

In plugin I have this:

```
namespace OCDI;

class ImportActions {
    public function register_hooks() {
        add_action( 'pt-ocdi/customizer_import_execution', array( $this, 'customizer_import' ), 10, 1 );
    }
}
```

So I tried this:

```
remove_action( 'pt-ocdi/customizer_import_execution', array( '\OCDI\ImportActions', 'customizer_import' ), 10, 1 );
```

But it does not work(

`customizer_import` function still working so the code in themes functions.php should run after plugins code.

I checked looks plugin loads all the main code in `after_setup_theme` action.

Can someone clarify why so?

It is not possible to make small changes to a plugin? Perhaps I can hire someone?

Kind regards

Comment: Check [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/370181/how-can-i-remove-a-hooked-action-created-by-a-plugin/370189#370189) answer.

Comment: @Ivan Shatsky Ok, thanks. Can I hire you please?)

Comment: In the first code snippet **non static** method is attached to the hook `array( $this, 'customizer_import' )`. Using the class name in `array( '\OCDI\ImportActions', 'customizer_import' )`  you are trying to detach a **static** method.

Comment: Write details to ivan(dot)shatsky(at)gmail(dot)com

Comment: @Ivan Shatsky emailed you